# How to transition along a path partially or by percentage only

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, transition

I am a beginner with d3 and currently can not use the newest version, but instead I am on version 3.x.

What I am trying to realize should be simple, but sadly I didnt find resources on how to do it:

The goal is to display a path in my svg. Then I want to display e.g. a circle and transition / move / trace the circle along the path. This works fine if I want the full path to be followed.

**But the goal is to follow the path only partially.**

What could I do if I want the circle to start from position 0 of the path and follow it until e.g. 25% of the path?

And then again, if the circle is at 25%, how can I follow from there to 50% of the path without starting over from position 0 of the path?

I will be very thankful for any input you can provide here. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I built my answer using this code from Mike Bostock (which uses D3 v3.x, as you want): https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1705868

First, I created a data array, specifying **how much** each circle should travel along the path:

```
var data = [0.9, 1, 0.8, 0.75, 1.2];
```

The values here are in percentages. So, we have 5 circles: the first one (blue in the demo below) will stop at 90% of the path, the second one (orange) at 100%, the third one (green) at 80%, the fourth one (red) at 75% and the fifth one (coloured purple in the demo) will travel 120% of the path, that is, it will travel all the length of the path and 20% more.

Then, I changed Bostock's function `translateAlong` to get the `datum` of each circle:

```
function translateAlong(d, path) {
    var l = path.getTotalLength() * d;
    return function(d, i, a) {
        return function(t) {
            var p = (t * l) < path.getTotalLength() ?
                path.getPointAtLength(t * l) : path.getPointAtLength(t * l - path.getTotalLength());
            return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
        };
    };
}
```

The important piece here is:

```
var l = path.getTotalLength() * d;
```

Which will determine the final position of each circle. The ternary operator is important because of our last circle, which will travel **more** than 100% of the path.

Finally, we have to call the transition, passing the datum and the path itself:

```
circle.transition()
    .duration(10000)
    .attrTween("transform", function(d) {
        return translateAlong(d, path.node())()
    });
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var points = [
     [240, 100],
     [290, 200],
     [340, 50],
     [390, 150],
     [90, 150],
     [140, 50],
     [190, 200]
 ];

 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
     .attr("width", 500)
     .attr("height", 300);

 var path = svg.append("path")
     .data([points])
     .attr("d", d3.svg.line()
         .tension(0) // Catmull–Rom
         .interpolate("cardinal-closed"));

 var color = d3.scale.category10();

 var data = [0.9, 1, 0.8, 0.75, 1.2];

 svg.selectAll(".point")
     .data(points)
     .enter().append("circle")
     .attr("r", 4)
     .attr("transform", function(d) {
         return "translate(" + d + ")";
     });

 var circle = svg.selectAll("foo")
     .data(data)
     .enter()
     .append("circle")
     .attr("r", 13)
     .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
         return color(i)
     })
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + points[0] + ")");


 circle.transition()
     .duration(10000)
     .attrTween("transform", function(d) {
         return translateAlong(d, path.node())()
     });

 // Returns an attrTween for translating along the specified path element.
 function translateAlong(d, path) {
     var l = path.getTotalLength() * d;
     return function(d, i, a) {
         return function(t) {
             var p = (t * l) < path.getTotalLength() ?
                 path.getPointAtLength(t * l) : path.getPointAtLength(t * l - path.getTotalLength());
             return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
         };
     };
 }
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
    
circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Coincidentally, I just made a dataviz with this kind of transition: https://gf.neocities.org/hmm/hmm.html If someone here at SO is also a F1 fan (very unlikely!), he/she may find this interesting.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. This is great and allows me to advance in my needs. Still I am unsure though, how i would now be able to "continue" the movement of the circles from their stopping position by some percentage value instead of restarting their path movement from position 0 each time.

Comment: For that new problem, I believe you should post a *new* question. Since this question is quite old, posting a new question (specifying precisely the new problem and linking this question for clarification) will attract way more attention!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That problem was actually mentioned in my original question, but I think it might got lost because it was not bold. I will open a new question then. Btw, just browsing through your d3 page, it looks amazing.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I saw the mention, starting on *"And then again..."*.. The thing is that it's always a good idea keeping **one** issue per question. It's easy to answer and, after all, posting questions is free!

Comment: You are absolutely right, thanks for pointing that out. I have marked your answer as accepted, because its great. The new question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43732890/how-to-move-along-a-path-but-only-between-two-specified-path-points