# How to move along a path but only between two specified path points

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, path, percentage

This question is about d3 version 3.x and path movements.

Imagine there is a path and a circle element, and I want the circle to follow that path in a transition, but only up to some percentage.
I was asking this before and got a great answer from Gerardo Furtado here: [My former question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676992/how-to-transition-along-a-path-partially-or-by-percentage-only)

Still, one question in this regards remains for me, and as I am a beginner, I couldn't find any working solution so far:

**How can i trace this path, lets say, from a point at 25% to a point at 50%, and then later from a point at 50% to a point at 60%?**

These numbers are just examples, any percentage value should be possible.

I need to avoid that the path movement always starts from position 0, but instead i want to start path movement from the current position the circle has reached already.

Hopefully I could express my question clear enough.

Thank you very much for any insight and help.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I agree, SO is not supposed to write code for me. I have tried for days with different approaches feasible in my limited knowledge, read a lot of resources, but none of these covers my goal and my attempts have not been successful. I don't really know what to search for anymore. Maybe im just missing the right keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have to agree with [LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43732890/how-to-move-along-a-path-but-only-between-two-specified-path-points#comment74515433_43732890), and I see that you also do. Since I answered your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43677305/5768908), I just needed to do some minor changes in the function. However, keep his advise in mind for the next times: when asking a question, show us some code you've tried, even if it **doesn't** work, because it shows effort.

Back to the question.

For this solution, I'll wrap everything inside a function named `move`, which accepts two arguments, the initial position and the final position (both in percentages):

```
function move(initialPosition, finalPosition) {
```

The initial position, as the name implies, set the initial position of the circle along the path. The math is this:

```
var start = path.node()
    .getPointAtLength(path.node().getTotalLength() * initialPosition);
```

Then, I slightly changed the function from my last answer to accept the initial and final positions:

```
function translateAlong(path) {
    var l = path.getTotalLength() * (finalPosition - initialPosition);
    return function() {
        return function(t) {
            var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l + 
                (path.getTotalLength() * initialPosition));
            return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
        };
    };
}
```

Here is the demo. Clicking on the button calls `move` with `0.25` (initial position) and `0.5` (final position) as arguments:

```js
var points = [
  [240, 100],
  [290, 200],
  [340, 50],
  [390, 150],
  [90, 150],
  [140, 50],
  [190, 200]
];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 300);

var path = svg.append("path")
  .data([points])
  .attr("d", d3.svg.line()
    .tension(0) // Catmull–Rom
    .interpolate("cardinal-closed"));

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var dataPositions = [{
  initial: 0.25,
  final: 0.5
}, {
  initial: 0.5,
  final: 0.6
}];


svg.selectAll(".point")
  .data(points)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 4)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d + ")";
  });

d3.select("button").on("click", function() {
  move(0.25, 0.5);
});

function move(initialPosition, finalPosition) {

  var start = path.node().getPointAtLength(path.node().getTotalLength() * initialPosition);

  var circle = svg.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 13)
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
      return color(i)
    })
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + start.x + "," + start.y + ")");

  circle.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attrTween("transform", function() {
      return translateAlong(path.node())()
    });

  function translateAlong(path) {
    var l = path.getTotalLength() * (finalPosition - initialPosition);
    return function() {
      return function(t) {
        var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l + 
            (path.getTotalLength() * initialPosition));
        return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
      };
    };
  }

}
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<button>Move</button>
<br>
```

PS: The function in this answer **does not** accept values bigger than 1. But you can try to change it if you need to do more than "one lap" in the path.

Comment: This is amazing work. Sadly I was not smart enough to figure out the math that you did in the translateAlong method. This should solve my needs. Thank you again for your great help!